# WPF / MVVM Design Suggestions

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm pretty new to WPF, and am looking for some guidance here.

I'm working on an application that will be used to print out work orders for our fulfillment department.

Right now I have 2 windows:  The first is the main screen, the second is a window with a gridview that will hold the work orders to print.

The first page will have several buttons on there.  Every button will open up the second window; however, depending on which button is clicked, the parameters passed into the service that will load data will be different.

What would be the best practices way of doing this?

- Is there way to define these parameters somewhere on the Button control, and then pass them through via ICommand/RelayCommand?
- Should I create a UserControl/ServerControl that will let me build in these additional properties?
- Something else I'm not thinking of?

**Edit:**

To give a rough example (and this is very oversimplified}, say i have 2 sets of criteria:  OrderTypes: {Rush, Today, Future} and Locations {Warehouse 1, Warehouse 2, Warehouse 3}

The main window would have a 3x3 grid of buttons, one for each combination.  I'd like to be able to specify on a single button "Expedite & Warehouse 1"; and then pass those parameters back to a single method, which would open the second window.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have `MainWindow` and buttons are placed in it.

1. Create a `MainWindowViewModel` and set it as `DataContext` for MainWindow.
2. Have an `ICommand` on your ViewModel and bind button Command with this `ICommand` so that *entry point for opening another window will be single*. For ICommand you can use either `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` whichever suits you best.
3. Now, comes the point where you need to open window and pass on parameter to it based on button type click. I would suggest to *have Enum depicting action need to perform based on different buttons*.

**Enum**

```
public enum ActionType
{
   Action1,
   Action2,
   Action3 and so on...
}
```

And bind from button like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CommandInstance}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Type local:ActionType.Action1}"/>

<Button Command="{Binding CommandInstance}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Type local:ActionType.Action2}"/>
```

where local will be namespace where enum is declare.

And in command execute delegate pass the enum value to another window constructor:

```
private void CommandMethod(ActionType action)
{
    AnotherWindow anotherWindow = new AnotherWindow(action);
    anotherWindow.Show();
}
```

and from action passed in constructor, you can check what parameter need to pass to service responsible for loading data.

Also, in case creating window from ViewModel doesn't seems right you can have Service wrapper over window Controls which is responsible for showing/closing window.

---

**UPDATE**

Since you want to pass multiple parameters from Views so maintaining enum for this will be cumbersome. You can **pass multiple values from View using [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

Let me explain with small example:

```
<Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}">
   <Button.Resources>
      <sys:String x:Key="Rush">Rush</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="Warehouse">Warehouse</sys:String>
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.CommandParameter>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValuesReturnConverter}">
          <Binding Source="{StaticResource Rush}"/>
          <Binding Source="{StaticResource Warehouse}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
 </Button>
```

where `sys` will be namespace for System in XAML:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

So, now you have liberty in XAML to pass many objects from XAML to your command parameter. All you have to do is to declare the resource under Button resources section and pass it as binding to converter.

***Converter code*** to convert it into list of parameters which can be passed to command as a single parameter object:

```
public class MultiValuesReturnConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.ToList<object>();   
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

***Command Method:***

```
private void CommandMethod(object parameter)
{
    // Now you have all the parameters here to take decision.
    IList<object> values = parameter as List<object>;

    AnotherWindow anotherWindow = new AnotherWindow(action);
    anotherWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: I really like this way because of the single entry point.  Is there a way i can specify multiple parameters there, or am I locked into 1?

Comment: You need to pass parameter from View only? If it can be deduced based on ActionType, i would suggest to create in ViewModel.

Comment: I posted a quick edit with a example of what i'm trying to accomplish.  Having a single ActionType could quickly get unwieldy; as i'd have lots of potential types

Comment: @JimB-  Please see the update in answer for passing multiple values from View to Command using IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: Opening another window inside your viewmodel? That defeats the purpose of the ICommand.

Comment: @Shoe - That's why i mentioned at last to have Service wrapper over it and delegate the responsibility to that Service for open/close window operation.

Comment: I think this is a very thorough answer but a very good case in point to my answer about convoluted abstractions in an attempt to rigidly follow a pattern.

Comment: Sorry but I am not in agreement with that. Having Service is perfectly legitimate for MVVM solution. `PopUpService`, `MessageDialogService` are most popular among those.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use some third party library, there really is no problem in simply passing the parameters through a click event into your other window's constructor. If your data is represented by a viewmodel you may also pass that viewmodel instead of the parameters themselves.

A point of MVVM is not "no code-behind". Many times you will end up without code-behind, but trying to develop applications this way leads you into convoluted anti-patterns that often are more work and more lines of code than simple click events and "the old way".

Treat your data as data, try to do all your work in testable viewmodels and never follow a pattern too rigidly lest you end up with mounds of unreadable abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

Before detailing any thing, I would advice you to use the third party library MVVMLight, it has many helpful features such as Messenger, its own RelayCommands etc ...

1. For passing parameters from a button to consume them in Commands, you can use the Tag property if you want to pass a parameter regardless of the type of the event, if you want to pass a parameter that is related to a certain Command(event) then CommandParameter is what you need :

[Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element. (Inherited from FrameworkElement.)

CommandParameter :

```
<Button Content="Parameterized Command" 
    Command="{Binding ParameterizedCommand}" CommandParameter={Binding SomeObject} />
```

1. I don't think at the level of your question that you need to create a UserControl unless you have more complicated scenarios.
2. You can use the Messenger class to pass information from ViewModel to another (this just a helper it's independent from the MVVM Pattern).
3. The MVVMLight has code templates that help you create ViewModels with ease.
4. The MVVMLight has many helpful snippets which you will find helpful.
5. Beware of Commands because they are not originally supported with all UIElements, they are only available with ButtonBase and its children and they work only to replace the Click event, to use Commands and CommandParameters with other UIElements and with other kinds of events you should use a sort of EventToCommand behaviours, MVVMLight has got that already ready for you

Hope I covered most important parts you may need.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans Well I think i got it wrong then, I was thinking about another scenario, I'll have it updated, thx for the remark

Answer (score 0):

The most easy and intuitive way (Using `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update the UI instead of `DependencyProperty`):

You create a property that'll be your `DataContext` for your `OrderViewModel` in `MainWindowViewModel`

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase // ViewModelBase should implement INotifyPropertychanged, unless you're using dependency properties
{
  private OrderViewModel _OrderViewModelInstance;
  public OrderViewModel OrderViewModelInstance 
  { 
     get{ return _OrderViewModel;} 
     set { _OrderViewModel = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged("OrderViewModel")} // Method from ViewModelBase
   }
```

Now, whichever way You're creating Your Order View:

- You instantiate `OrderViewModel` in `MainWindowViewModel` (Let's say when a button gets clicked) with desired parameters.
- you bind the Order view's `DataContext` to `OrderViewModelInstance` in XAML. You might want to create an additional variable that tells you when the window is visible.